# How do I manually get autotest to run on specific test files? Editing .autotest in rails app root has no effect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I have to keep manually typing in rspec /etc/etc/etc.rb and would prefer to just use autotest.

Any suggestions?

Kind regards

Comment: Um, install autotest or guard?

Comment: I have autotest hence being able to edit it. I want to choose what test files it runs.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The way autotest works is, when you save a file that has a test, or a test file, it will automatically run the test. Are you trying to limit what it runs, or trying to tell it what to run? Because you won't need to do that if it's installed properly.

Comment: I found a much better solution. Ruby-test for sublime-text it does exactly what I want to do and all inside the text editor. All I have to do is start spork from terminal and I'm good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a much better solution. **Ruby-test** for sublime-text it does exactly what I want to do and all inside the text editor. All I have to do is start spork from terminal and I'm good to go.